# HTTP response headers that cause side effects for other resources on the same origin

Tags: http, http-headers, response-headers

I have a server which hosts resources for several users on the same hostname.  For example:

- http://example.com/alice/blog.html
- http://example.com/bob/cat.jpg
- http://example.com/carol/todo.txt

I would like to allow users to specify their own response headers for resources within their directories, similar to what is done on AWS S3.  For example, Carol may want her TODO list readable from scripts on another domain, so she might want `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` set for `todo.txt`.

While I want this feature to be as flexible as possible, I cannot allow just any response headers to be specified, as some response headers have side effects for the entire origin or hostname.  For example, `Set-Cookie` could be used for one person's directory, but the user agent could then make a request to someone else's directory with the cookie value.  As another example, a user could set `Strict-Transport-Security`, potentially locking out other users from using normal HTTP.

What other HTTP response headers have the potential for side effects for the entire origin, rather than just the resource that was requested?  My list so far:

- Alt-Svc
- Public-Key-Pins
- Server
- Set-Cookie
- Strict-Transport-Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than blocking response headers that could affect the entire domain I would recommend a slightly different approach and specify a white list of response headers that are definitely okay to use. There could be new, experimental or browser-specific headers that are non-standard but potentially affect the entire domain for a user with a specific browser.

I would suggest that the following headers are safe to use and should be everything your user needs to modify:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
- Access-Control-Expose-Headers
- Access-Control-Max-Age
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers
- Age
- Allow
- Cache-Control
- Content-Disposition
- Content-Encoding
- Content-Language
- Content-Length
- Content-Location
- Content-Range
- Content-Type
- Date
- ETag
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Link
- Location
- Pragma
- Retry-After
- Transfer-Encoding

For static content such as files and html pages I would not set Content-Range or Content-Length manually. The server should set many of these headers automatically. Nevertheless overriding them might make sense for some users. Transfer-Encoding can be used to add `gzip` or `deflate` during transfer if your server supports it, but must not be used with HTTP/2.

Also Location, Allow and Retry-After only make sense for certain status codes. You might want to omit them

Comment: Thanks for this list, this is indeed an option I was considering.  I think I'll add `X-*` as well.  Some of my clients would want a way to add tracking headers and such.